# Redirect to a URL which contains a 'variable part' in Flask (Python)

Tags: python, redirect, python-2.7, flask, url-routing

I'm trying to redirect to a URL in Flask. The target URL that I'm trying to redirect to has a variable like this `/dashboard/<username>` which has a view as follows,

```
@app.route('/dashboard/<username>')
def dashboard(username):
    return render_template('dashboard.html', username=username)
```

How do I redirect to this URL using the Flask's `redirect()` & `url_for()` functions. I have tried this,

```
return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

which works fine as index is an URL without any variable part (`/index`) in my application. But, how do I do it for URLs which have variable paths?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will want to create your URL with `url_for` by giving it the name of your URL, the keyword `arg`, and value for your URL parameter in the following manner:

```
return redirect(url_for('dashboard', username='foo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The point '.dashboard' is important

```py
return redirect(url_for('.dashboard', username='foo'))
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as the accepted answer.